# How to copy array of struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct, copy

I have

```
struct vehicle {
  int available_supply=10;
  int is_assigned_to_route=1;
};

vehicle vehicle_info [2];
```

how to make a copy of vehicle_info?

i want something like

```
vehicle inital_vehicle_info [2]=vehicle_info;
```

could someone give me a hint, please?

Comment: thanks to show me this link. found a solution there :)

     customers inital_customer_info [2];
       copy(customer_info + 0,customer_info + 2,inital_customer_info);

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not directly copyable — it does not matter what they are arrays *of*.

You can and should use a wrapper:

```
// Use std::array instead
std::array<vehicle, 2> vehicle_info;

// Now this is easy:
std::array<vehicle, 2> initial_vehicle_info = vehicle_info;
```